# Get only used meta_values

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, get-posts, publish

this is how I'm getting the meta values:

```
$apart_locations = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'postal_location' ORDER BY meta_value ASC" );
```

This is how I'm getting the published posts of a custom post type:

```
$apartments = $wpdb->get_col( "
                SELECT DISTINCT( post_id ) 
                FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
                WHERE meta_key IN( $fields_string ) AND 
                      post_id IN ( SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts 
                      WHERE post_type = 'tvr_apartment' AND 
                            post_status = 'publish' ) ORDER BY rand() " );
```

So my concern here is

how can i get the meta_values only from the ones that are used by at least 1 published post?

any idea how?

-EDIT-

I'm trying to Do this because the first query returns metas that are unnused:

[image]

Comment: you are trying something like this, I'm talking about the right column "The Basics" http://innsales.com/inns/the-kerr-house-bed-and-breakfast/ or some other concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question right, and thus don't know if this answer goes into the right direction... Is this what you're trying to achive?

```
$apart_locations = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta AS wppm
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts AS wpp ON wppm.post_id = wpp.ID
    WHERE wppm.meta_key = 'postal_location' AND wpp.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY wppm.meta_value ASC" );
```

Comment: looks like! I will let you know ;) thanks!"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not doing the right thing here. Why don't you use WP_QUERY? It will get you posts in what ever way you want and from the posts returned you can get your meta values.

```
$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'your post type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key' => 'your key',
    'meta_value' => ' ',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$new_query = new WP_Query($params);
```

Filtering something like this should straight away give you all the posts that are using the meta_key.
Hope this helps!

*Update:
[Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) is an example from the codex itself to query using multiple custom fields.
Unless you have hundreds of fields this approach should work very well. Also if you are writing SQL queries, you have to tune them so that they won't be a bottleneck for performance.

Comment: The thing is that i want to make a `<select>´ with all the used meta_values in order to filter the posts... byt the way the posts query is from a external theme wich i am only tweaking

Comment: My question is, why do you want to it the other way round when you can get the posts directly? What is the aim/advantage of doing it in that way?

Comment: i want to get the meta values isolated, i am not even getting the posts yet... check my screenshot

Comment: I would still suggest using the approach i suggested. Edited my answer to give some more info.

Comment: I am not looking for a post query, i am looking for a meta_values query only, but that are used by at least one post...

Answer (score 0):

Try `WHERE meta_value != ''` to check for empty values.

This should be your final query:

`$apart_locations = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'postal_location' AND meta_value != '' ORDER BY meta_value ASC" );`

EDIT: This query should help you get the values you want so you can combine it with a post retrieval query.